# 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found when using react native fbsdk

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk in my application.
My react-native version is:0.39.1

I followed the all steps and when I build my project I'm getting the following error.

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There was a breaking change in React-Native 0.40 where the headers have been moved to React namespace.
If you use a version prior to 0.40 you have to change `'React/RCTBridgeModule.h'` to `'RCTBridgeModule.h'` inside of `RCTFBSDKAppEvents.m`

See here for more info : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0

Or you can upgrade your react-native version: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of react-native-fbsdk ( which is `0.5.0`) only works with RN `>=0.40`.

For RN `<0.40`, do the following:

1) Uninstall react-native-fbsdk:

`npm uninstall react-native-fbsdk --save`

2) Reinstall with an older version and link it:

`npm install react-native-fbsdk@0.4.0 --save`

`react-native link react-native-fbsdk`